# How can an angle be put into a window on-screen on BGE?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm lost, not a clue...
I have an alarm box sitting on the dash of my crane (see below).
The left window and knob are the settings for the Low Alarm, which squeals if the angle of the boom goes below a set angle. The High Alarm on the right side squeals if the angle goes above the set angle. The window in the middle shows the actual angle of the boom.
In the Logic Bricks (in BGE), the boom is limited to 600 ticks (debug) for travel up and down. This equates to 0 degrees, horizontal, where it is right now, and 85 degrees, on the vertical travel. (The boom is the elongated cube above the alarm box, pivoting on the right end, just for testing purposes.) When the low and hi angle knobs are turned, the set angle needs to show in the appropriate window. Equally, when the boom changes angle, that number needs to appear in the center window. (For info, the switch on the bottom right corner is to turn the audible warning on, up, and down to turn it off. This works, just added for the curious.)
Can somebody please give me a clue how to do this?

[image: Crane Boom Angle Indicator and Alarm Box]

Comment: Can anyone offer even a PARTIAL answer? Any ideas on how to proceed? Thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: I found various Q & A's that have information I used to make this work. Here's the list: How can I update a text object dynamically in the Blender Game Engine? BGE How to make text appear when winning or losing a game? Is it possible to have a property sensor detect another property? How do I format an integer text object using just logic bricks? How can a changing angle be measured and used as a property in BGE Logic Bricks? Some of this needs to be changed to what I need, but I thought I'd conglomerate the information just in case of interest.